# working through regex expression to print specific word

Tags: python, regex

I have a word like `tiger.hill.forest.env2`

for some words forest may not be present so what I am trying to get is `tiger.hill` if forest is not present and `tiger.hill.forest` if forest is present.

I have worked through the regex of the first part

`expression = re.search(r"(\w+.)(\w+.)\bfor", txt)`

it gives output tiger.hill but I expect to be `tiger.hill.forest`

Comment: Please give an example of an input string where you want output `'tiger.hill'`.

Comment: input string for output like `tiger.hill` is `tiger.hill.city.env2`

Comment: linked question  doesn't answer my question